# SQL replace with serial number for the specific occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Input table has strings like this:

```
Col_Name
---------------
YXNYNXYYZY
YYZZY
-- and 100's of rows
```

I want to find specific occurrence of character Y, and create output field like this:

```
Col_Name
----------------
1,4,7,8,10
1,2,5
```

I am trying to find solution with sql functions like replace, len, charindex, etc,, but unable to arrive to the output.  Please help.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing. What problem are you encountering when trying to accomplish this?

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?   include any error messages.

Comment: In SQL, you generally want each column (in each row) to contain *one* value (whether that be a string, int, etc). SQL Server has two data types *designed* for holding multiple values - tables, themselves (in the form of rows, for repeating instances of the same "type" of value) and XML. Is you're requested output format fixed in stone?

Comment: Sorry guys, i am not that expert in SQL.. i edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but you should consider changing your model because this aproach may be slow and should not be SQL Server job's.

```
declare @search char(1) = 'Y'

; with input(string) as (
    Select * From (values('YXNYNXYYZY'), ('YYZZY')) as input(string)
), find(id, string, pos) as ( => get 1 row each Y found and its position
    select 0, string, CHARINDEX(@search, string, 0) From input
    Where CHARINDEX(@search, string, 0) > 0
    Union All
    select id+1, string, CHARINDEX(@search, string, pos+1) From find
    Where CHARINDEX(@search, string, pos+1) > 0
)
--Select * from find => 1 position per row
Select STUFF( --=> concatenate all position by string
    (
        Select ', ' + CAST([pos] AS Varchar(10)) 
        From find f
        Where (string = r.string) 
        Order By string, id
        For XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('(./text())[1]','Varchar(100)')
  ,1,2,'') AS x
From find r
Group BY string
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of function we can bring those values

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPosition] 
(
@txt varchar(max),
@Pat varchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@tab TABLE 
(
 ID int
)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @pos int
Declare @oldpos int
Select @oldpos=0
select @pos=patindex(@pat,@txt) 
while @pos > 0 and @oldpos<>@pos
 begin
   insert into @tab Values (@pos)
   Select @oldpos=@pos
   select @pos=patindex(@pat,Substring(@txt,@pos + 1,len(@txt))) + @pos

end

RETURN 
END

GO
```

Call Function

```
SELECT 
stuff(
(
    SELECT ','+ cast(ID as nvarchar(4)) FROM dbo.[GetPosition] ('YXNYNXYYZY','%Y%')  FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be trivial to do with a scripting language like php or python.  Dump the entire dataset to an array and check each value.  Event 100's of rows would not be an issue.

1. [Load the CsV File](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
2. Search array for values.

//psuedo code (untested)

```
$Data = str_getcsv('c:\data\dumpeddata.csv');

foreach ($Data as $LineNo => $LineDetails) {
  foreach($LineDetails as $ColNo => $ColData){
   if (strpos($ColData , 'Y') !== false){
     $Found .= "\nLine:$LineNo,Col:$ColNo";
    }
 }
}
echo $Found;
```

You'll be surprised how fast this runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @n int = (select charindex('Y',col_name,1) from tablename)
declare @l int = (select len(col_name) from tablename)
declare @res varchar(100) = ''
while @n <= @l and (select charindex('Y',col_name,@n) from tablename) <> 0
begin
set @res = @res + cast(select charindex('Y',col_name,@n) from tablename as varchar) + ' '
set @n = (select charindex('Y',col_name,@n) from tablename) + 1
end
select @res
```

This gives you an idea. If this has to be done repeatedly, it is better to wrap this in a function.